# How can I draw polyline in three.js?

Tags: three.js, geometry, polyline

I would like to draw a polyline(using x, y values) to create a shape.
For example, when you draw a polyline with a set of coordinates
-(0,0), (0,2), (2,0), (0,0), it will create a rectangular shape.
How could I do it in three.js ?

And, after drawing a shape using polyline, could I give a height (z value) to the shape and make it 3D ?

Thanks.

Comment: _(0,0), (0,2), (2,0), (0,0)_ will give you a triangle, not a rectangle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what you really want. As you want a polyline, not a curve.

Based on `THREE.Shape()` and [this](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes) example:

```
var points = [
  new THREE.Vector2(0, 0),
  new THREE.Vector2(2, 0),
  new THREE.Vector2(2, 2),
  new THREE.Vector2(0, 2)
];
var shape = new THREE.Shape(points);
shape.autoClose = true; // the shape will be closed automatically, thus we don't need to put the fifth point
var geometry = shape.createPointsGeometry();
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "yellow"}));
scene.add(line);
```

Based on `THREE.Geometry()`:

```
var points3D = new THREE.Geometry();
points3D.vertices.push( // here you can use 3-dimensional coordinates
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.5),
  new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(2, 2, 2),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 2, 3),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.5) // there is no autoClose function here, thus we need the fifth point
);
var line2 = new THREE.Line(points3D, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "red"}));
scene.add(line2);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/Lnakqj3u/) example with both solutions